# How to load data to Spring Ehcache when the application starts

Tags: java, ehcache

I want to load the data from database into cache memory using Spring ehCache when the application starts i.e when the server starts before any other method is called. I dont want to use a constructor. Please help me.

Comment: If you're creating the EhCache as a bean (using the `@Bean` annotation) then you can add the data in the method that returns the bean instance. Can you show us the code that you're using to create the EhCache object?

Answer (score 0):

One option for this is to use a [Spring `BeanPostProcessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-extension-bpp) and have it work on the `CacheManager` bean, get the `Cache` and load it.

Another option is to have a [`BootstrapCacheLoader`](http://ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/configuration/configuration#cache-warming-for-multi-tier-caches) configured for doing this. You can also consider extending from [`MemoryLimitedCacheLoader`](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/2.9/index.html?net/sf/ehcache/store/MemoryLimitedCacheLoader.html) to help you stop loading once you have reached cache capacity.